# How can I make text into links

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, helper

I am working on a project and I need help with making any text into a link so, to sum up, what I need help with is I am creating a page where someone needs to attach a link to a word or more like how you can add links to words on google docs [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pklK9.png)

Comment: Please format your question properly, it's not clear what you're asking. Are you looking for HTML anchors? (<a> tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use link() method to add link to a text.

```js
// link() example
var title = "Example";
var url = "https://youtube.com";
var result = title.link(url);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;

// Form example
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", displayLink);

function displayLink() {
  let title = document.getElementById('title').value;
  let url = document.getElementById('url').value;

  // Write Javascript code!
  const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
  appDiv.innerHTML = title.link(url);
}
```

```html
<label>Example with link()</label>
<div id="demo"></div>

<br /><br />
<label>Example With Form</label>
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Title" value="" id="title" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Url" value="" id="url" />
</form>
<button id="myBtn">Add Link</button>
<br /><br />
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but I do understand the link tag but I wanted to do something like if you have used an application called "Linktree"  where you have a textbox and you add a URL to the text box and you get a clickable text which has a link embedded inside of it and I was wondering if anyone knew how I could do that.

Comment: ohhh I see now. I'm see if i can figure that out.

Comment: I'm currently working on my site, that why i was on stack(i was looking for help) but ill try later

Comment: @VandanaKanojia Ive updated the answer. Your use case is more or less the same. Instead of hard coded string & url in the answer you would get the values from a text box. Are you using any framework of pure javascript?

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid  I am mostly using javascript and I am trying to make something similar to link tree where anyone can add a link to a piece of text .

Comment: @VandanaKanojia Glad i was able to help. Would be great if you could mark the answer as accepted as it would help others who are looking for similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="https://example.com/">Your Text Here</a>
```

The  attribute refers to a destination provided by a link. The a (anchor) tag is dead without the  attribute.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but I do understand the link tag but I wanted to do something like if you have used an application called "Linktree"  where you have a textbox and you add a URL to the text box and you get a clickable text which has a link embedded inside of it and I was wondering if anyone knew how I could do that.